# Can't understand these notations

Tags: calculus

$(r , \infty) \cup {\infty}$

Can anyone explain what does this mean in mathematics? What does union sign mean here? I know what it means in probability, but how is it applied here? Does this mean it can be either finite or infinite number?

How about this: $p\in R+\cup{\infty}$?

Please try not to confuse me.

Comment: Wouldn't it be $p\in \mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$ instead of $p\in\mathbb{R}+\cup\{\infty\}$? If it is the first one, then it means $p$ can be either a real number or $+\infty$ itself, which it's not a real number.

Comment: Oh, I get it... you meant $R_+ \cup \{\infty\}$.

Comment: As a general rule, the meaning of the symbol $\infty$ depends on context, as it is used to mean very different things in different places.

Answer (score 1):

$(r,\infty)$ is all the real numbers above $r$.  Then $(r, \infty)\cup\{\infty\}$ means a set that includes all the real numbers above $r$, and also $\infty$ as well.
Since $\infty$ is not a real number, the meaning depends on what else is happening in the current problem.
$\mathbb{R}_+\cup\{\infty\}$ is the same, but $\mathbb{R}_+$ is all the positive real numbers; $\mathbb{R}_+=(0,\infty)$